# Would a "death-note-rule-puzzle" tag be useful for the site?

Tags: discussion

Recently some user(s) posted a lot of questions about Death Note rules interaction. To me it is like some puzzling game with the rules of the DN.

Would a tag for these questions be useful?

Comment: I'm absolutely against those because they are borderline off-topic, and are almost never 100% answerable with in-universe knowledge. Answers would be opinion-based and this isn't how SE works.

Comment: While we do seem to get a good couple of these, I don't see why the normal death-note tag isn't sufficient

Comment: [tag:death-note-rules] *might* be okay, though I'm not convinced [tag:death-note] alone is insufficient. I don't think it's a good idea to add "puzzle" though.

Answer (score 5):

These "What would happen if" questions are no different from "What would happen if Goku fights Madara?". Almost always unanswerable and off-topic.

So no, I am against such a tag.

Comment: Like [this](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14175/in-mirai-nikki-what-happens-if-your-phone-turns-off) ?